# Starting at a particular tab index and stopping at the end

Tags: c#, linq

On a tab page, there are 33 textboxes and I'm trying to get the values of textboxes with tabindex 13 through 33. I've set all the tab indexes to these numbers but cannot get it to work for some reason.

The code I currently have:

```
int startTabIndex = 13;
int endTabIndex = 33;

foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        if (ctrl.TabIndex == startTabIndex || ctrl.TabIndex <= endTabIndex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The  `MessageBox.Show(ctrl.Text)` is just a test to see if it is working.

Also, can this be accomplished by using LINQ, and how?

---

I changed my code to use LINQ to grab values of textboxes (the name and the text) per the answer provided by Steve. How exactly would I go about checking if the values were passed (like showing the text in a message box or something)?

```
int startTabIndex = 13;
int endTabIndex = 33;

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(t => t.TabIndex >= startTabIndex && t.TabIndex <= endTabIndex)
    .Select(x => new System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Name, x.Text))
    .ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.Value);

foreach (var d in dictionary)
{
    MessageBox.Show(d.Value);
}
```

When I click on the insert button, nothing happens. Is there something I am missing?

---

Steve gave me an excellent example and it works but it starts at the end of the textboxes (tabindex 33) and proceeds all the way backwards to the beginning (tabindex 13). How to reverse this?

Comment: A hint for future questions: If you specify your goal upfront, there will be no need to go though the back-and-forth edits and appending "update" sections. Those are no updates, those are changes of requirements. Requirements changes may cause frustration on the answerer's side, same as they may do so on a developer job. See [a related meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/238706) if you want more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in one line with OfType (to get only textboxes) a Where (to select just the textboxes inside the tabindex range) and finally a Select to extract the strings from the Text property of the TextBoxes

```
int startTabIndex = 13;
int endTabIndex = 33;

List<string> texts = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                             .Where(t => t.TabIndex >= startTabIndex && 
                                         t.TabIndex <= endTabIndex)
                             .OrderBy(b => b.TabIndex)
                             .Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
```

To get a `Dictionary<string,string>` the code could be changed to

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
              .Where(t => t.TabIndex >= startTabIndex && 
                          t.TabIndex <= endTabIndex)
              .OrderBy(b => b.TabIndex)
              .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(x.Name, x.Text)
              .ToDictionary(z => z.Key, z => z.Value);

foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string>kvp in dic)
      MessageBox.Show($"Key={kvp.Key} = {kvp.Value}");
```

*UPDATE*
Added also the OrderBy to ensure an enumeration according to the TabIndex to answer the last request of the OP (thanks to [CodingYoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228458/codingyoshi)).

Comment: how would I assign the returned values to a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` ?

Comment: Please explain better then because this KeyValuePair is somewhat unclear. What would be the Key and the value?

Comment: sorry. the key is the name of the textbox and the value is the text of the textbox.

Comment: and how would I be able to add those values into a insert query? sorry, I'm new to C# and am still learning.

Comment: sorry, one last thing, how would I go about displaying the values from your examples? Like showing it in a message box or something to see if it is getting the value(s) of the textboxes?

Comment: unfortunately nothing is happening when I click on the insert button, no message box is showing..

Comment: Please use the debugger to look at the code flow. I have no way to see your whole program and understand what's going on. You have a Controls collection without any container before. This seems to be the Controls collection of the form. If the TextBoxes are inside another container (like a TabPage) you need to use the Controls collection of the precise control that contains the TextBoxes

Comment: yeah, its under the 1st tabpage, and the insert button is under the 1st tabpage too, so wouldn't that fix that? I mean, I did get one message box to show when I was on the tabindex specified but I had to do a .ToString() for it to show.

Comment: tabPage.Controls (or whatever name you have given to the Insert page) then not Controls. Without the exact container name you are referencing the Form.Controls collection

Comment: worked, thanks for your patience. sorry, one more question, it grabs the last index first and starts it way backwards. Any way to reverse this?

Comment: Do you know how to reverse it so it grabs the 1st value first and the last one last?

Comment: @user2101411 use `OrderBy` to order it by tab index firstly and then do a select.